# Как изменить глобальную переменную в условии PHP

Tags: php

Если не использовать условия, а менять переменную в функции, то всё работает и она меняется на 1, а условиями так и остаётся 0. Извините, если вопрос очень простой, я просто совсем чайник еще в php)

```
$password_err = 0;

function register(&$err) {
    if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['password_confirmation']) {
        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        setcookie('login', $login);
        setcookie('login', $password);
        header('Location: ' . '/index.php');
    }
    else {
        $err++;
    }
}

function verify($password_err) {
    if (1!=1) {
        echo 'ываываывп';
    }
    else {
        register($password_err);
    }
};

if($_POST) {
    verify($password_err);
}
```

Comment: Я вообще ничего не понял. В итоге где конкретно надо поменять и что ?

Comment: надо поменять переменную $password_err

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `verify` принимает аргумент по значению, а не [по ссылке](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.references.pass.php):

```php
function verify($password_err) {}
//             ^^
```

Поэтому в функции `register` вы изменяете значение *локальной переменной* `$password_err` функции `verify`:

```php
function verify($password_err) {
    if (1!=1) {
        echo 'ываываывп';
    }
    else {
        // $password_err == 0
        register($password_err);
        // $password_err == 1
    }
};
```

Чтобы изменить глобальную переменную, объявите `verify` аналогично `register`:

```php
function verify(&$password_err) {}
//             ^^^
```